# Convert object with 'long.property.name' property to object tree

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash.js

I want to transform such object from:

```
foo = {
    42: 'foo', 
    'a.b.c[0].42': 'bar',
    'a.b.c[0].43': 'zet',
    'a.d.c[0].42': 'baz'
}
```

To:

```
bar = {
    42: 'foo',
    'a.b.c[0].42': 'bar',
    'a.b.c[0].43': 'zet',
    'a.d.c[0].42': 'baz',
    a: {
        b: {
            c: [{
                42: 'bar', 43: 'zet'
            }]
        },
        d: {
            c: [{
                42: 'baz'
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I have written implementation, but it looks ugly.
Do anybody know how to improve the function below?
We use `lodash` in my project so that can help with basic operations.

```js
function convertToTree(rowObjectData) {
  function it(object) {
      return _.reduce(object, function (finalObjectData, value, key) {
          var pathParts = key.match(/(.+?)\.(.+)/);

          if (pathParts) {
              delete finalObjectData[key];

              var deepObject = {},
                  containerObject = {},
                  arrayMatch = pathParts[1].match(/(.*)\[(.)]$/);

              deepObject[pathParts[2]] = value;

              if (arrayMatch) {
                  containerObject[arrayMatch[1]] = [];
                  containerObject[arrayMatch[1]][arrayMatch[2]] = it(deepObject);
              } else {
                  containerObject[pathParts[1]] = it(deepObject);
              }

              finalObjectData = _.defaultsDeep(finalObjectData, containerObject);
          }

          return finalObjectData;
      }, object);
  }

  return _.assign(_.cloneDeep(rowObjectData), it(_.cloneDeep(rowObjectData)));
}
        
var object = {
    42: 'foo', 
    'a.b.c[0].42': 'bar',
    'a.b.c[0].43': 'zet',
    'a.d.c[0].42': 'baz'
};
        
console.log(convertToTree(object));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to take a stab at it I would write something like this:

```js
function convertToTree(rowObjectData) {

  function isArrayKey(key) {
    return _.last(key) == ']';
  }
  
  function setValue(object, value, key) {
    var parts   = key.split(/[.[]/),
        last    = parts.length - 1;

    for (var i=0, current=object; 
         i < parts.length; 
         i++, current = current[k]) {
      var p = parts[i],
          k = isArrayKey(p) ? parseInt(p) : p;
      if (i == last)
        current[k] = value;
      else if (current[k] == undefined)
        current[k] = isArrayKey( parts[i+1] ) ? [] : {}
    } 
    
    return object;
  } 
  
  return _.reduce(rowObjectData, setValue, _.cloneDeep(rowObjectData) );
}
        
var object = {
    42: 'foo', 
    'a.b.c[0].42':    'bar',
    'a.b.c[0].43':    'zet',
    'a.d.c[0].42':    'baz',
    'a.d.c[1]':       'zaphod',
    'a.d.c[2][0].49': 'beeblebrox',
};
        
console.log(convertToTree(object));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Which also allows multiple sequential arrays (`c[0][1].49 = 'foo'` and doesn't require the last key to be an object (`c[0] = 'foo'`)

Comment: Thank you, looks good! I found the shorter solution. Please check the same question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43645169/4449154).